# Does the C# 16 Byte struct limitation mean I can't use strings in structs?

Tags: c#, string, struct

I have a struct:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly string Str1;
    public readonly string Str2;
}
```

According to the Internet, you really should only use structs if their size is 16 bytes or less. If more, performance issues can happen. From various searches, a string stores 2 bytes per character. This means that if you have a string in a struct, it could only have 8 characters at most, assuming it's the only string in your struct. In my example, that'd be split among both fields I have.

Elsewhere, however, I've read that only the string reference is put in the struct, not the string itself.

My question is: Does the 16 byte recommendation/limitation of C# structs mean that I basically can't use strings in them. I like taking advantage of structs sometimes (especially the cannot-be-null parts of it), so I want to know if there's still a way to use them while following the recommendations.

EDIT: Poor choice of words on my part. Indeed it's not a limitation of the language, but rather a recommendation based on performance to not exceed 16 bytes in one's structs. I think I'm falling victim to premature optimization here: Perhaps I should only worry about this limitation if I see actual performance problems in my application, rather than fretting over small numbers of bytes.

Comment: Well string is reference type, and also, it's a guideline, not a limitation.

Comment: The string is not contained within the struct. Only a reference to the string is.

Comment: Note that there's no "limitation" here. There's a guideline, but that doesn't mean that you *can't* have larger structs.

Comment: More importantly, don't make mutable structs.

Comment: For future reference: "According to the internet" is a non-definitive source for any information. When you cite a reference for something, include a link to that reference. I'm aware of the source you're referring to in this case, but my initial reaction when reading that sentence was an almost instinctive desire to downvote because of that phrasing without a link to the source. "The internet" is a very large place full of darkness, monsters, and utter nonsense, and citing a vague reference to it as a source is simply meaningless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Advice regarding the 16-byte threshold should be considered out of date.  The .NET Runtime optimizes operations on structures below a certain size (which used to be 16 bytes, but has since increased to I think 24); the cost per byte increases when structures exceed that size, but that doesn't mean one should use a class for everything larger than that.

The cost of creating a new structure is proportional to its size.  The cost of creating a new class object is proportional to its size plus some significant additional overhead.  The cost of copying an existing structure is proportional to its size, with a penalty for structs over a certain size.  The cost of copying a reference to an immutable class object is fixed and small.

Creating a structure of any size and copying it once or twice will always be cheaper than creating a class object of the same size and copying the reference likewise.  If the structure or class reference would get copied millions of times, even a 12-byte class might outperform a 12 byte structure.  For values in between, the break-even size for class vs. structure will depend upon the number of times a struct or class reference would get copied, but unless a type is really big or would be copied many thousands of times, the extra cost to copy structures will still be cheaper than the extra cost to create class objects.

With regard to the fact that a structure contains strings, one should regard a reference to an immutable-type object as having a cost of 4 or 8 bytes on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.  Since a `string` field does not "hold" a string but merely *identifies* one, a struct with two `string` fields would thus take 8 or 16 bytes, regardless of the lengths of the strings identified thereby.

Comment: `The .NET Runtime optimizes operations on structures below a certain size (which used to be 16 bytes, but has since increased to I think 24)` --> Do you know where this might be documented?  Searching all of Google and the only places discussing this are a handful of SO answers from you specifically.

Comment: @Tinister: I don't know if/where the increase is documented, but used a debugger to inspect the machine code generated by various simple test programs, and observed optimized machine code for structures up to 24 bytes, and a call to a memory-copy function for larger ones.

Answer (score 5):

`String` is a reference type, so in this case, you are only holding 2 references to your two `string`s however long they are. The 2 references, are 4 bytes each on a 32-bit system, and 8 byte each on a 64-bit system. They contain the memory address of your strings.

The guideline of this `16 byte struct limitation` is probably because when you are passing a struct (vs. a class), the values get copied. If the struct is large, then a lot of memory copying will be done, which will negatively impact the performance.

Comment: Note that on x86 builds, pointers are indeed `int`-sized at 4 bytes, but on x64, they're the size of `long`s at 8 bytes

Comment: If I recall correctly, the size of `int` varies depends on whether you are x86 or x64. The size of `int` on x64 is Int64, i.e. the size of `long` on x86.

Comment: The size of `int` fortunately doesn't change. `IntPtr` and friends do change size.

Comment: "int" in the C# world is a synonym for Int32 i.e. 32 bits = 4 Bytes.

Comment: Thanks guys, I learned something new today, and I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this particular case will only store the reference to `string` - and references are always sized according to architecture. This means references are 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on x64 platforms. Don't forget your program will usually be made to run on either x86 or x64.

You can check whether a particular type will pass by reference or by reference (ie take up full size or just pointer sizes) by seeing whether it is deifned as a `class` (reference) or a `struct` (value). If you're using Visual Studio or Xamarin, just select a type name and hit 'f12' to see the metadata for that type - which will include `class` or `struct` delcaration.